# JS giving wrong value when executing thru selenium web driver

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am using JS to find out the number of classes of certain type. When I execute JS in webdriver, it gives me the wrong value. When I execute the same JS on Firebug console, it gives me the right value.

Webdriver:

Returns 0

```
int Rects = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript<int>(" $('.optimization.flighting .interval').size()");
```

Returns 4

```
$('.optimization.flighting .interval').size()
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more information on the page itself, those elements you are trying to target, version of jQuery etc etc, I can only guess at an answer (which I will happily delete if proven wrong), but I suspect it's being the JavascriptExecutor needs a little more pushing when returning values:

```
int Rects = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript<int>("return  $('.optimization.flighting .interval').size()");
```

Specifically, adding the `return` statement before the actual Javascript, in a similar way you can add `return` to C# methods.

(Also, why you are not using the built in element finding mechanisms?)